# Python - Document Clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, document

I am new to Python and checking for a sample program to cluster documents based on the key words. Found the program [clustering](http://brandonrose.org/clustering) in this and converted this program into python.

While running program which is converted into python getting the error. few other error have fixed by adding the import statement of the library.

Or if you suggest me some sample program which feeds in mutiple document and cluster it is also fine.

Portion of the code getting error given below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
print(synopses[20])
x=TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                                 min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1,3))
get_ipython().magic('time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(synopses)')
print(tfidf_matrix.shape)
```

Thanks,
Sijo

Comment: What's the error? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Below given the error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster_analysis.py", line 223, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic('time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(synopses)')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magic'

Comment: You clearly have no idea what that program is doing... can't even fix a trivial thing like that... stop programming by copy&pasting code you do not understand. You job is to program, not to use Google...